# HTML5 pattern exclude words

Tags: regex, html, textarea, spam

I want to exclude some unwanted words in an input field of textarea using the pattern function in HTML5.

so I want exclude word inside a text like 'viagra' and 'cialis'

How can I code this?

Comment: When you want to do spam filtering, you should do it server-sided. Most spam bots will just post the form content directly and ignore the pattern.

Comment: On most websites I know which are plagued by spam, it's not just viagra and cialis anymore. Nowadays, the spammers advertise just about anything one can buy.

Comment: I've already inserted a captcha, but the seem to fill in the forms manually ...(?)

Comment: Many spambots use optical character recognition to break captchas. Many have algorithms tailored for commonly used captcha libraries. For more information about automatic captcha solving, see http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/PWNtcha#

Comment: ...and when OCR isn't working, there are people in China who solve 1000 captchas for you for $1 (I am not making this up: http://boingboing.net/2012/01/09/virtual-sweatshops-versus-capt.html)

Comment: Some sites use a slider as captcha. Does this work as a better prevention?
http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/qaptcha/

Comment: adapting my spambot for that will take about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this regex :

```
^((?!viagra)(?!cialis).)*$
```

As explained in the post : [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Answer (score 0):

you can use it

```
<input type="text" pattern="[^(^viagra$|^cialis$)]">
```